# Cannot change file association in Win7Ent

Tags: windows-7, filetype

I need to change file association for PDF's from Acrobat to Chrome via command line. There are specific business reasons for this. We run a VDI environment, and this script will be pushed via GP on Win7Ent VM's. I need to make the change and have it update live if possible, just as if I changed it in the windows file association GUI, which I can't go around and do for 700 people.

This should be a simple thing. When I run my script, it reflects the changes using **ftype** and **assoc**, but Windows itself doesn't make any change. Files still show an Acrobat icon and open in Acrobat.

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" GOTO FTx64
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" GOTO FTx86

:FTx64
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command" /v @ /t REG_SZ /d ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf" /v "Application" /t REG_SZ /d "chrome.exe" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf\OpenWithList" /v "g" /t REG_SZ /d "chrome.exe" /f
FTYPE pdffile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%1"
ASSOC .pdf=pdffile
EXIT

:FTx86
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command" /v @ /t REG_SZ /d ""C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1"" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf" /v "Application" /t REG_SZ /d "chrome.exe" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf\OpenWithList" /v "g" /t REG_SZ /d "chrome.exe" /f
FTYPE pdffile="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%1"
ASSOC .pdf=pdffile
EXIT
```

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Did you try killing explorer.exe and restarting after your script succeeded to see if that changes things? Might be the shell doesn't recognize your changes and you need to tell it "somehow".

Comment: Yes, I restarted explorer.exe, and a logoff/reboot shows no change either.

Comment: Also, if there is a better method, vbs or powershell for example, I'm open.

Comment: There are another registry which prioritise apps to be used. Path: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf`

Comment: I have that in my script above already. Do you see anything out of place there?

Comment: Change `"g"` to `"a"` in that registry path.